# Can I have some Taiwan restaurant sentences?

Tags: mandarin

Every time I go to a restaurant in Taiwan I say weird weird stuff. They always understand, but I'm sure I'm saying it unnaturally.

Also, occasionally I don't entirely catch what they're asking. Which definitely wouldn't be a problem if I knew what to expect.

Anyways, there's only a limited number of things to say like what to call a waiter, ("where do I pay?", "table for 3, please" and the other things commonly said or heard) can people who know what they're doing post a few below.

Thanks for helping me not sound like a buffoon!

Answer (score 4):

I'm from the mainland. But I think you can use these in Taiwan:

where do I pay?: 请问在哪里付钱？

Table for 3, please : 3人用餐，谢谢

Can I have a look at the manu？  ： 我能看看菜单么？

Can you bring something to drink? : 能来点喝得么？